# Java scanner useDelimiter doesn't work in French

Tags: java, internationalization

I've got a string of floating point numbers like

```
1.0000\0.0000\0.0000\0.00000\1.0000\0.0000\0.0000
```

which I need to parse. I use the Java Scanner using the backslash as the delimiter. It has been working for years in English. Just today I put on French as the default language and in French it fails to parse, i.e. it doesn't find the next double. I also have Hebrew on the computer and it parses in Hebrew with no problem. Just French is a problem.

Here is the code:

```
static float[] parseMultFloat( String tmp1) {
    float [] ret1 = null;
    double[] val = new double[32];  // arbitrary limit of 32
    int i, n = 0;
    if( tmp1 == null) return null;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(tmp1).useDelimiter("\\\\");
    while(sc.hasNextDouble() && n < 32) {
        val[n++] = sc.nextDouble();
    }
    if( n>0) {
        ret1 = new float[n];
        for( i=0; i<n; i++) ret1[i] = (float) val[i];
    }
    return ret1;
}
```

With the debugger I can single step up to the `while(sc.hasNextDouble)`. In English and Hebrew it will find all my numbers. In French it just jumps over the while and leaves `n=0`.

Is there any other way to get my numbers, which will also work in French?

Comment: Because ... that's not french. The decimal point (period) would be a comma.

Comment: Sorry, DICOM generated the string, not me. DICOM is English based so I never even noticed the period. I thought it was the delimiter which wasn't working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scanner is locale aware. For French a double would look like 0,00023

Set the US locale before reading the next double, if the format does not change.

```
sc.useLocale(Locale.US);
```